# ¿Cómo extraer números enteros de una lista dada para comprobar si son números primos?

Tags: python, integer

Tengo la función para saber si son primos, pero me falta extraer los números enteros de la lista:

La función para saber si es número primo es la siguiente:

```py
def es_primer(nombre):

    if nombre == 1:
        return(print('No es primer'))
    elif nombre == 2:
        return(print('Es primer'))
    else:
        for i in range(2, nombre):
            if nombre % i == 0:
                return(print('No es primer'))
        return(print('No es primer'))
```

Pero en una variable tengo dos números de tal manera:

```
s = [10,3]
```

Lo que quiero saber es si 10 y 3 son números primos, pero si meto en la función:

```
#Primero he transformado s en integer de tal forma: 

int_s = list(map(int, s))
```

Pero si pongo en la función que he creado:

```
print(es_primer(int_s))
```

Me da error porque me dice que sigue siendo una lista y no un `integer`... ¿me podéis ayudar?

Comment: Podrías recorrer la lista y en cada iteración verificar si el valor de la lista es un primo. Para ello debes conocer la forma básica de recorrer iterables (como listas) en Python. Saludos

Comment: ¿nombre? ¿primer? ¿has traducido eso automáticamente del francés?

Comment: A estas alturas ya deberías saber como extraer elementos que cumplan una cierta condición. Es la tercera pregunta en 24 horas.

Comment: list(map(int, s)) aplica la función int a cada elemento de la lista s y devuelve una lista. En conclusión, lo que devuelve es una lista de enteros (asumiendo que todos los elementos de la lista pueden convertirse en enteros). Que resultado esperabas? Por que convertir una lista de numeros en un solo numero si quieres saber si cada numero de la lista es primo? Eso no tiene sentido. Te recomiendo practicar un poco tu lógica de programación.

Comment: Quizá leí mal la pregunta y realmente sabes que lo que obtienes es una lista. Si ese es el caso, Python no sabe mágicamente que quieres procesar cada elemento de la lista por separado. Tienes que indicárselo. Mauricio te dio una pista de lo que deberías hacer.

Answer (score 0):

podés usar una list comprehension de un for para recorrer los elementos de s:

```
s = [10,3]

resultados = [es_primer(el) for el in s]
print(resultados)
```

opcionalmente todo junto

```
print([es_primer(el) for el in s])
```

o con un for explícito (no se puede hacer todo junto:

```
resultados = []
for el in s:
    resultados.append(es_primer(s))

print(resultados)
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me ha servido para poder acabar el ejercicio.